Navigation between webview (in fragment) and different fragments
In my application I have a bottom menu with some items. Every item represent a fragment.

HomeFragment -> I have a listview with some elements representing some websites. When I click on one element, open a webview in a fragment and load website's homepage.
WebviewFragment -> navigate within web page, then I click one item and show that fragment.

Now I'm programming two back and forward buttons so that when I press back from the current fragment it takes me back to the webview with the web address I had before clicking the fragment. Then let me navigate back to the history of the webview.
Same thing for the forward button. These buttons are found in the action bar and I manage them in the main activity.
In my activity main:
btnBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Fragment fragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
            if(fragment instanceof WebViewFragment)
                navigateBackWithWebview(fragment);
            else
                navigateBackWithoutWebview(fragment);
        }
    });


public void navigateBackWithWebview(Fragment fragment) {
    String tag = fragment.getTag();
    if (tag != null && tag.contains("Webview")) {
        WebView webView = fragment.getView().findViewById(R.id.webview);
        if (webView.canGoBack())
            webView.goBack();
        else {
            fragmentManager.popBackStack();
            frammentiRimossi.add(fragment);
        }
    }

}

public void navigateBackWithoutWebview(Fragment fragment) {
    if (fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount() > 1) {
        frammentiRimossi.add(fragment);
        fragmentManager.popBackStack();
    }
}

public void navigateForwardWithWebview(Fragment fragment) {
    String tag = fragment.getTag();
    if (tag != null && tag.contains("Webview")) {
        WebView webView = fragment.getView().findViewById(R.id.webview);
        if (webView.canGoForward())
            webView.goForward();
        else {
            Fragment fragmentToAdd = frammentiRimossi.pop();
            openFragment(fragmentToAdd, fragmentToAdd.getTag());
        }
    }
}

public void navigateForwardWithoutWebview(Fragment fragment) {
    if (!frammentiRimossi.isEmpty()) {
        Fragment fragmentToAdd = frammentiRimossi.pop();
        if (fragmentToAdd instanceof WebViewFragment) {
            WebView webView = fragmentToAdd.getView().findViewById(R.id.webview);
            //fragmentToAdd.restoreWebViewHistory(webView, list);
        }
        openFragment(fragmentToAdd, fragmentToAdd.getTag());
    }
}

In my WebView fragment :
public WebBackForwardList saveWebViewHistory(WebView webView) {
    if (webView != null) {
        return webView.copyBackForwardList();
    }
    return null;
}

public void restoreWebViewHistory(WebView webView, WebBackForwardList history) {
    if (webView != null && history != null) {
        //delete current history
        webView.clearHistory();
        //restore previous history
        for (int i = 0; i < history.getSize(); i++) {
            WebHistoryItem webHistoryItem = history.getItemAtIndex(i);
            String url = webHistoryItem.getUrl();
            webView.loadUrl(url);
        }
        WebBackForwardList webBackForwardList = webView.copyBackForwardList();
        Log.d("DEBUG","list="+webBackForwardList.getSize());
    }
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if(history != null)
        restoreWebViewHistory(webView, history);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    history = saveWebViewHistory(webView);
}

In this way, when I click back from fragment, show webview with correct url, but when I click again change the fragment.
